# Close the popup after Update or Insert the data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form which open as a popup and it is used to insert or update the data.There is one button which updates the data in data base but does not close the popup.It remains open after update/insert.

i tried the following code but could not achieved

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['modify']))
{
$aba11=$_POST['aba11'];
$aba12=$_POST['aba12'];
$aba13=$_POST['aba13'];
$aba21=$_POST['aba21'];
$aba22=$_POST['aba22'];
$aba23=$_POST['aba23'];
$aba31=$_POST['aba31'];
$aba32=$_POST['aba32'];
$aba33=$_POST['aba33'];
$aba41=$_POST['aba41'];
$aba42=$_POST['aba42'];
$aba43=$_POST['aba43'];
$sampleid=$_GET['sampleid'];
$sql="UPDATE tblaba SET aba11=:aba11,aba12=:aba12,aba13=:aba13,aba21=:aba21,aba22=:aba22,aba23=:aba23,aba31=:aba31,aba32=:aba32,aba33=:aba33,aba41=:aba41,aba42=:aba42,aba43=:aba43 where sampleid=:sampleid";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':sampleid',$sampleid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba11',$aba11,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba12',$aba12,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba13',$aba13,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba21',$aba21,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba22',$aba22,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba23',$aba23,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba31',$aba31,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba32',$aba32,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba33',$aba33,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba41',$aba41,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba42',$aba42,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba43',$aba43,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
{
$_SESSION['msg']="Sample Updated successfully";
self.close ();
}

IF (@@ROWCOUNT == 0)
$sql="INSERT INTO  tblaba(sampleid,aba11,aba12,aba13,aba21,aba22,aba23,aba31,aba32,aba33,aba41,aba42,aba43)VALUES(:sampleid,:aba11,:aba12,:aba13,:aba21,:aba22,:aba23,:aba31,:aba32,:aba33,:aba41,:aba42,:aba43)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':sampleid',$sampleid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba11',$aba11,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba12',$aba12,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba13',$aba13,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba21',$aba21,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba22',$aba22,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba23',$aba23,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba31',$aba31,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba32',$aba32,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba33',$aba33,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba41',$aba41,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba42',$aba42,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':aba43',$aba43,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
{
$_SESSION['msg']="Sample information updated successfully";
self.close();

}

?>
```

Comment: You cannot mix Javascript with php that way.

Comment: Can you add code for opening popup with markup?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, might this help you in the future [mre]

Comment: @Vantiya<a  onclick="window.open('aba-edit.php?sampleid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?>','_blank','height=700,width=1200 top=200 left=350,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no')"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> UPDATE</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening new tab on click of URL it's not a POPUP actually.

To close tab after your desire operation you suppose to do like this.

replace

```
self.close();
```

with

```
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
```

or

```
echo "<script>close();</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy!

I can imagine two solution for this problem.
1: easier way: after the database operation redirect to the correct page

```
header("location: ".{landing_page}."); die;
```

2: create a web service api, use javascript on button click event, and call the created web service api. If it returns successful, just simply close the popup, if there was any error, you can show it to the user

I hope it will help to you.

Chris